# Play embedded video again but without internet

Tags: video, offline, vimeo

I have a infinitely looping slideshow where couple slides will have embedded Vimeo videos. The Vimeo videos are embedded into the PHP code using their "embed video" code with iframe.

Assuming that the videos already played once with internet available, is there a way to play the videos again without internet? This is incase the internet cuts off and we still want to have the videos playing.

My current setup is that I have Javascript that loops through each section and starts animation for that specific section.
Below is the case for slides that have videos. I use the player.js play() function to start playing the video, but looks like I require internet connection each time.

I want to build it so that I only require internet once to load and play the videos and afterwards it should just replay without needing internet.

I already looked through [the Vimeo's dev portal](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/guides/start), but could not find anything I can use.
If anyone has ideas & advices, help is much appreciated.

```
//javascript
function loopThroughChildDivsWithDelay() {
let parentDiv = document.getElementById('parent_section');
let childDivs = parentDiv.children;

    // Start the loop with the last child ... absolutely stacked divs, last one is the one that's at the top.
    printChildWithDelay(childDivs.length - 1);

}

function printChildWithDelay(index) {
let parentDiv = document.getElementById('');
let childDivs = parentDiv.children;

    if (index >= 0) {
        // add the animation start class
        childDivs[index].classList.add('animation_start')
    
        // detect last animation and move on to next.
        switch (childDivs[index].id) {
            case "video":
                let video_section = childDivs[index];
                const iframe = document.querySelector('.video_player' + index);
                const player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);
    
                player.play().then(function (data) {
                    // PLAY THE VIDEO
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.error('Video cannot play: ', error)
                }) ; // start video
    
                player.getDuration().then(function(duration) {
                    // `duration` indicates the duration of the video in seconds
                    let fade_start_time = duration - 2;
                    let timer = null;
    
                    // when video is at fade_start_time, add animation class and move to next slide
                    timer = setInterval(function () {
                        player.getCurrentTime().then(function(seconds) {
                            let flat_seconds = Math.floor(seconds);
                            if (flat_seconds === duration) {
                                clearInterval(timer);
                            }
                            if (flat_seconds === fade_start_time) {
                                video_section.classList.add('animation_end')
                                video_section.addEventListener('animationend', function () {
                                    // listen for animation end
                                    printChildWithDelay(index - 1);
                                })
                            }
                        });
                    }, 1000);
                }).catch(function(error) {
                    console.error("Video Not Loaded: getDuration Rejected", error)
                });
                break;
            default:
                console.log('id not found')
        }
    }

}
```

I honestly don't know where to begin.
I've read through the [Vimeo Dev Portal](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/guides/start) and could not find anything.

May be I missed something.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to lern how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question to add your research findings, and why they don't help you. -- Are you aware that you need to cache or store all the videos somewhere? Depending on quality and length, this takes a serious amount of space. What did you find on that matter? -- Commonly such web sites do not provide such mechanisms to protect their business model. What does their contract allow?